# Has anyone run VxWorks on a desktop PC as a target

Tags: vxworks

Can I use a desktop PC to run VxWorks as the operating system?  In other words, can a standard PC be used as a target processor?  I'm not talking about hosting Workbench and a VxSim on the same machine.  Rather, I'm considering running just VxWorks (and my application) on a PC.

It seems feasible as long as we can configure a board support package, and write or obtain device drivers for the I/O cards on the PCI bus.  What I wonder is, has anyone actually done this?

I'm interested in saving a bit of money on hardware over a single board computer and cPCI backplane by using a spare desktop sitting around unused.  The application is for a test set to be used in a lab.  So, I don't need the portability, etc. of a typical embedded processor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally Possible.
There are a number of BSPs that work out of the box: pcPentium4 is the canonical one, but with the new processors/bridge combos, there are specific BSPs available.  Those BSPs start with itl_
Boot device can be a USB flash drive, a floppy drive or a hard disk.

Comment: Thanks.  I feel silly having missed the pcPentium bsp.  On the other hand, I never would have found the itl_ packages on my own.  I will try it out on a old laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I used to do it all the time. These days it is even simpler as you can run VxWorks on top of VmWare and use one PC as both host and a target system. Contact your friendly local Wind River TAM/FAE as they might provide you with preconfigured project/BSP.

Comment: The VmWare setup is very interesting!  I'm keeping it in mind for future projects. 

My current project involves a lot of high speed I/O and a ~60 ms main loop.  I'm not sure that VMware hosted VxWorks will give me the tight interrupt latency bounds that a native VxWorks provides.  Wouldn't the latencies be determined by the OS VMware is running on?

Comment: To run VxWorks on VMware, shouldn't there be a iso image or something? How and where can I get the vxworks iso image?